# My WIFI connection has high ping periodically

Tags: wireless-networking, latency

My friends don't have this problem. I tried to change the router but it didn't work. My laptop is Predator 15 with Killer Wireless n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter.

[Here is the screenshot when pinging google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iulFd.png)

Comment: Try a local ping, like the wifi access point / router, in case it's just wider network issues. But my instinct is *"Forget it Jake, it's [Wifi]town".* (Or just hardware not fully supported by the upgrade)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be any one of a number of things.  The most likely is that you are simply in a noisy (to WIFI frequencies) environment, but it could also be an issue with the card in your PC and/or its drivers, or simply be a result of traffic on your wireless network.

FWIW, these pings are not "high" - and there is no packet loss.   The latencies also appear to be somewhat random rather then periodic - which is why I believe the most likely cause is a noisy environment.

If it were me I'd be breaking out my Android phone and using a Wifi scanner to tell me whats going on in the various frequencies and jump to a new frequency.   If the router supports it, I'd also look to see if I was connecting on the 2.4 gig or 5 gig band - the 5 gig band is likely to be less susceptible to noise.

Comment: I tried both 2.4GHz and 5GHz. There are 5 people using this wifi, and my laptop is the only one has this problem. I test ping google on my phone and it is stable between10 and 20. I believe this is periodic because it occurs every 8-10 pings.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the driver's problem. It didn't occur until I upgraded the system to Windows 10 Pro and restore everything last month.

Comment: Your comment makes me think that a driver issue is most likely - unless your other devices are connecting on the 5g band while your laptop is on the 2.4g one or vice versa

Answer (score -1):

Remove apps that are related to your network one by one! Like VPN apps, VirtualBox, and everything that maybe make changes on your network! I do that and one of them has a problem with my network! now it's error-free and my ping is ok!